# Can I use any film star (female) pictures as my own profile picture?

Tags: women, sin, social-media

I have been told that using any female picture is forbidden in Islam, because Islam don't like showing off any female publicly.

So can I use their (film stars/models) picture or it will be a sin even using their pictures publicly even if those pictures are already available over the internet to everyone?

Comment: You could use images of flowers, nature, cats etc..

Comment: yes , but this question just came in my mind when I read that thing

Comment: According to me, first, the're doing a sin by showing off, second, you're promoting it. So, it's better to be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As dear Hamza Islam correctly remarked:

> As its a general rule never to show pics of females on public or
>   social websites, who are uncovered

Particularly if the female is Muslim ...

Meanwhile, as a related verse, you can refer to Surah a-Nour (I reckon verse 31) as well.

---

You remarked:

> ... even if those pictures are already available over the internet to
>   everyone?

But how can you be sure that the owner of this photo is satisfied... Beside, it can extend the issue of vice (seeing non-mahram ...)

---

Good luck و من الله التوفیق

Answer (score 0):

No. It's a sin. 
You're indirectly  promoting them. And this causes more people to look at them etc. and they'll gain more popularity and money which is haram, just because of you. 
So don't upload it.